# Simple Robotics to do with teenagers

Tags: robotics

I am trying to get a robotics club started in my school. But I am wondering if I started what could I get the kids to make. They would be aged between 14-18, some with electronics knowledge. So I need some cheap project ideas. I am looking for a project cost of about £3 per device, this only applies to specialised parts such as motors, relays/H-Bridges, sensors and materials for chassises. Other parts such as microcontrollers we have lying around.

Comment: Battlebots? What better way to attract kids and still teach about electronics. You can build them pretty cheaply with a couple motors and a microcontroller. I've made one for under $20.

Comment: If you're into building robots, don't forget to commit to the [Robotics Proposal](http://http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40020).

Comment: @Rocketmagnet Done :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try **BEAM robots**, you find tons of them when you google. They should be cheap and easy projects to build and understand.

some of the link are :
http://www.instructables.com/id/Solar-Powered-Miniball-Wannabe/

http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-make-a-mini-solar-robot/

http://www.robotroom.com/Appetizer.html

http://www.tombot.net/beamrobots.html

Apart from that if you want to include microprocessor then you can do some **light chaser** or **line follower** or **obstacle avoidance** which are fairly easy to understand and build provided you have prior knowledge about micro controllers.

Comment: I totally agree. The sandwich-container line-follower (it's a BEAM project in spirit) is an excellent beginning project, and I am very in favor of starting with analog components. I have no affiliation with this book or the author, I just think it's an excellent reference for beginners. [Robot Building for Beginners (Technology in Action) by David Coook](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1430227486/ref=pd_lpo_k2_dp_sr_1?pf_rd_p=486539851&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe-1&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=1893115445&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=112ZB3NSJMYHJT3HK6JW)

Answer (score 0):

you may find many cheap and simple robotics projects ideas in internet. I found many such kind of projects. If you are interested, once follow this link:

http://www.elprocus.com/robotics-based-project-ideas/

I hope you may get required information from the above link.

And also there are few robotics projects which are very interesting and easy to understand.

Some of them are as follows:

Visible light follower Robot

Live Human detection and alerting Robot

Wall Follower Robot